# Error al actualizar Referencia de Servicio a la nueva versión del SII de AEAT

Tags: vb.net, webservice, aeat-sii

Estaba trabajando con un proto en VB.NET para registrar Facturas Emitidas y Recibidas para el SII de AEAT basados en la V_05.

La semana pasada, AEAT emitió una revisión V_06. Mi prototipo empezó a fallar ya que la propiedad `IDVersionSii` seguía conteniendo el valor de la revisión anterior.

Siendo novel consumiendo Servicios Web vi una opción en VBNet que permitía, desde las referencias a los servicios, cambiar la "Configuración de referencia de servicio". Cambié la dirección a la nueva versión:

http://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_06/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl

Aparentemente las clases y tipos de ese servicio se han actualizado correctamente (ya incluyen los apartados referentes a operaciones de seguros y el valor permitido para `SIIVersion` ya es el que corresponde: `0.6`.

Sin embargo, cuando hago la llamada al `siiSOAPClient` en lugar de devolverme un objeto Respuesta de Suministro me lanza una excepción:

> Excepción producida: 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' en mscorlib.dll
>
> El tipo de contenido text/html del mensaje de respuesta no coincide con el tipo de contenido del enlace (text/xml; charset=utf-8). Si usa un codificador personalizado, asegúrese de que el método IsContentTypeSupported se implemente correctamente.
>
> (...) Agencia Tributaria - Se ha producido un error (...)

Me temo que al actualizar las referencias algo no ha ido bien con el tema de los puertos o los Bindings del archivo `app.config`.

Me gustaría que alguien me pudiera concretar a qué se debe este error porque seguro que en los meses que quedan la AEAT vuelve a redefinir los servicios web y volveré a encontrarme con el mismo problema.

Nada de esto me pasa si, SIN modificar las referencias a los servicios, voy a la definición del tipo `SIIVersion` y cambio el literal "0.5" a "0.6". Pero claro, mis clases se quedan "obsoletas" con respecto a la versión actual (y subsiguientes) y entiendo que no es una solución válida.

Comment: Quizá sea importante la "Advertencia" que me da el compilador tras actualizar la definición de los servicios Web.

Comment: Advertencia de la herramienta personalizada: No se puede importar wsdl:port
Detalles: Se inició una excepción al ejecutar una extensión de importación WSDL: System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportBindingElementImporter

Comment: Error: URI no válido: no se puede determinar el formato del URI.
XPath al origen del error: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactRecibidas.wsdl']/wsdl:service[@name='siiService']/wsdl:port[@name='SuministroFactRecibidas'] 002 SII DR U:\Private\(...)\002 SII\Service References\srvFRecib\Reference.svcmap

Comment: Yo acabo de añadir una referencia de servicio con esa url que proporcionas, he creado un nuevo `siiSOAPClient` y despues  he llamado a `Open` y no me ha dado ningun problema. Indica en que momento te lanza la excepción (que método estas llamando?)

Comment: He añadido la llamada a Open (que no es necesaria) y no me da tampoco error. Mi código es:  
        `Dim Ws As New srvFEmit.siiSOAPClient  

        'Ws.Open()

        Ws.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = myCert
        'Fix
        'Ws.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = True

        SerializeFE(objSumFE)

        objSumFEAns = Ws.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(objSumFE)`

Comment: El problema es que yo no tengo certificado ni ningun objeto que pudiera enviar como test, con lo que no puedo probarlo en mi equipo. A ver si alguien que trabaje con ello puede echarte un mano. Siento no poder ayudarte mas

Comment: He investigado un poco, y algunos dicen que lo siguiente soluciona el problema. Yo lo dudo, pero si quieres probar...`Panel de Control/Programas y Caracteristicas/Activar o desactivar caracteristicas de windows/Net framework 3.5/Activacion http de WCF`

Comment: hola, pero cuando actualizaron, cambiaron la url ? o esta es la misma solo que con funcionalidad mejorada, porque podrias haber usado la opcion de update que proporciona el web reference. O sino rcomendaria que elimines completo la web reference y vuelvas a agregarla

Comment: @Leandro. Sí cambiaron la url. Anteriormente era (...)/V_05/(...) y ahora la han pasado a (...)/V_06/(...). Es muy lógico pensar que habrá más revisiones hasta el lanzamiento definitivo, por lo que me gustaría entender qué está fallando.

Comment: recomendaria que elimines la web reference y la vuelvas a crear, de esta forma aseguras que el proxy se actualiza correctamente. Ademas realiza un rebuild del proyecto para asegurar que toma las modificaciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema solucionado. Al actualizar las referencias al servicio web se modificaba el archivo app.config

El problema aparecía en el nodo <bindings>, donde Visual Studio borraba parte de la configuración de seguridad necesaria para los servidores de la AEAT.

La "auto-configuración" (resultado de actualizar referencias) incorrecta es:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="siiBinding">
            <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

y la configuración correcta es:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="siiBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Supongo que el html que me devolvía pretendía avisar de problemas de autentificación por certificado.

Answer (score 0):

En Visual Studio, abres un proyecto nuevo de Winforms con Vb.Net.
El el explorador de soluciones seleccionas el proyecto y en el menú contextual seleccionas Añadir -> Referencia de Servicio

En la dirección pones la siguiente url:

"http://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_06/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl"

y te abre un servicio con las siguientes funciones:

- AnulacionLRFacturasEmitidas
- ConsultaLRFacturasEmitidas
- SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas